# Not able to set queue in from in email activity in Dynamics 365 using workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow

I'm trying to set a queue in from recipient using a custom workflow when creating an email.
The workflow runs correctly in the sandbox pattern but does not work in the production method.

I've checked my workflow, it works fine, but the queue reference is automatically removed after email creation. The same behavior occurs when I create an email from Dynamics CRM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be that the queue's entity reference will change between your Sandbox and Production environments.

The workflow stores the entity reference with the underlying Guid and will not be able to reference the production Queue because the ID will be different.

You might find that if you deactivate the workflow you can't re-activate it because the references are missing.

To fix it you either need to manually modify your workflow to have the correct reference or use a configuration entity which will have a look up to the queue you want to send as and then have a coded workflow activity to retrieve the entity reference.

Means you can configure the workflow values between environments.